# Python and Pandas object assignment

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I recently started learning python for data analysis and I am having problems trying to understand some cases of object assignment when using pandas `DataFrame` and `Series`.

First of all, I understand that changing the value of one object, will not change another object which value was assigned in the first one. The typical:

```
a = 7
b = a
a = 12
```

So far `a = 12` and `b = 7`. But when using Pandas I have the following situation:

```
import pandas as pd
my_df = pd.DataFrame({'Col1': [2, 7, 9],'Col2': [1, 6, 12],'Col3': [1, 6, 9]})

pd_colnames = pd.Series(my_df.columns.values)
list_colnames = list(my_df.columns.values)
```

Now this two objects contain the same text, one as `pd.Series` and the second as `list`. But if I change some column names the values change:

```
>>> my_df.columns.values[0:2] = ['a','b']

>>> pd_colnames
0       a
1       b
2    Col3
dtype: object

>>> list_colnames
['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3']
```

Can somebody explain me why using the built-in `list` the values did not change, while with `pandas.Series` the values changed when I modified the data frame?

And what can I do to avoid this behavior in `pandas.Series`? I have a data frame which column names sometimes I need to use in English and sometimes in Spanish, and I'd like to be able to keep both as a `pandas.Series` object in order to interact with them.

Comment: "First of all, I understand that changing the value of one object, will not change another object which value was assigned in the first one." I don't know where you got this from, but it's totally incorrect for mutable values. It happens that integers are immutable, so your first example does not demonstrate behaviour with lists or Series objects

Comment: As an aside, I see far too many people constantly doing `some_series.values.tolist()` or `list(some_series.values)`. The majority of the time, it’s completely unnecessary. On the rare occasion that you do need a list, you can simply use `some_series.tolist()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `list()` is creating a new object (a copy) in `list_colnames = list(my_df.columns.values)`. This is easily tested:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = list(a)
a[0] = 5
print(b)
---> [1, 2, 3]
```

Once you create that copy, `list_colnames` is completely detached from the initial df (including the array of column names).

Conversely, `my_df.columns.values` gives you access to the underlying numpy array for the column names. You can see that with `print(type(my_df.columns.values))`. When you create a `Series` from this array, it has no need to create a copy, so the values in your `Series` are still linked to the column names of `my_df` (they are the same object).

Answer (score 0):

> First of all, I understand that changing the value of one object, will not change another object which value was assigned in the first one.

This is only true for immutable types (`int`, `float`, `bool`, `str`, `tuple`, `unicode`), and not mutable types (`list`, `set`, `dict`). [See more here.](https://medium.com/@meghamohan/mutable-and-immutable-side-of-python-c2145cf72747)

```py
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> b = a
>>> b[0] = 4
>>> a
[4, 2, 3]
```

What is going on is `list_colnames` is a copy of the `pd_colnames` (through the call of the `list` function), where `pd_colnames` is a mutable type related to the `my_df`.